# How to disable the power button on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, power

I have the following settings set in my Power Options settings:

[image]

However, it still does not stop my computer from being turned off when the power button is pressed. My cat often jumps onto my computer and presses the power button and my computer instantly turns off, despite the above options being set.

I have even tried placing objects over the power button but she will knock them off or just press down on them enough to press the power button regardless.

Is there any way to *completely* disable the power button without opening my case and physically removing the wires? (I do not want to do this).

Comment: Your cat presses and holds the power button? There is no way to disable a power button without literally disabling it, which also means, it cannot turn your device on. Have you considered a docking station or elevating the laptop on something?

Comment: It's a desktop PC and yeah she will jump on top of it and press and hold the power button while walking over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disconnect the power button inside the case, possibly connect a replacement button elsewhere that your cat can't reach or step on.

Power buttons have a legitimate and valuable purpose, and they operate by communicating with the hardware essentially directly.